# Prove that if $f$ is onto $B$, then $(f \vert M):M \rightarrow B$ is a bijection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $F=\{X \subseteq A: (f \vert X):X \rightarrow B\}$, where $X \rightarrow B$ is one-to-one. Consider the partially ordered set $(F, \subseteq)$. $M$ is maximal element in $F$.

Prove that if $f$ is onto $B$, then $(f \vert M):M \rightarrow B$ is a bijection.

First we show that it is one-to-one, which is $(f \vert M)(a)=(f \vert M(b)) \Rightarrow a=b$. Now we show that it is onto. If $x \in M$ and $y \in B$, we have $(f \vert M)(x)=f(x)$ and $f(x)=y$, which leads that $(f \vert M)(x)=y$, hence it is onto B. Now we have shown that the function is both one-to-one and onto, that means it is bijective.

I do not know if I have done anything correct and every help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You haven't used the fact that $M$ is maximal, which is a clue that there's something wrong with your proof.  In particular, how do you know (in the second line of your last paragraph) that $f(x)=y$?

Comment: How could I use that M is maximal? About that f(x)=y, I looked at my notes and I do not remember how I got that. My teacher noted that it is wrong to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Since $M\in F$, $f|M$ is one to one.

Suppose $f|M:M\to B$ was not onto. Then there is some $y\in B$ with $y\not\in f[M]$. Since $f:A\to B$ is onto, there is some $x\in A$ with $y=f(x)$. Note that $x\not\in M$, and so $M\subsetneq M\cup\{x\}$. But $f|M\cup \{x\}$ is one to one, so $M\cup \{x\}\in F$. This is impossible, because $M$ is maximal.